# PhantomJS - Login with jquery is not working in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, phantomjs

```
page.open('http://localhost:3000', function() {
page.evaluate(function() {
    $('#username').attr('value', 'username');
    $('#username').change();
    $('#password').attr('value', 'password');
    $('#password').change();
    $('.btn-login').click().submit();
});});
```

I'm using jquery to login. And using `.change();` to trigger an event. This code works fine for linux but not working for windows. Am i doing it wrong or is there any other way to solve this issue in windows?

Comment: `but not working for windows` In what way? Is it the server that is not working on windows or PhantomJS? What versions are PhantomJS on Linux and Windows?

Comment: Maybe it's better to `$('#password').trigger('change');`?

Comment: I'm using phantom 2.1 in both linux and windows. And i also tried `$('#password').trigger('change');` it didn't work.

Comment: Phantom js is not working in windows.

Comment: PhantomJS is not working on windows? Or the script is not working?

Comment: the script is not working in windows. whereas the same script works in Linux.

Comment: You should use `page.onError` callback to check for errors. What versions are PhantomJS on Linux and Windows? How do you run the script from command-line? (show) Does this `http://localhost:3000` work for you on Windows in a normal browser?

Comment: There are no errors. I'm using phantomjs 2.1 for both windows and linux. I'm not running from command line. I'm using nodejs and using phantom npm to run the code. Yes, `http://localhost:3000` works on windows in a normal browser. I ran the jquery script in chrome in windows and the authentication worked. But not in phantom browser.

Comment: `nodejs and using phantom npm` Oh, well in this case there is a universe of possibilities of what could go wrong! No use in discussing further without seeing the node code.

Comment: The code mentioned in the question is the only code I'm using for authentication and nothing further.